# Apache spark cassandra dataframe load error

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

I have an error with Spark-Cassandra load. Pls help!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste errors as text, in addition to images - this will allow to find this question by search engine...

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This is [known bug in the alpha version of Spark Cassandra Connector 3.0](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/Nxp_bnaOZWc). You need to use [3.0.0-beta version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12/3.0.0-beta) that was released this week.

P.S. You don't need to create `SparkSession` instance in Zeppelin - it's already there. You can set properties for Cassandra in the Interpreter settings, or even pass via `option` when reading or writing...

Comment: I change to 3.0.0-beta but I have an error org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Lscala/Function1;Lscala/runtime/IntRef;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: it looks like you're using Spark compiled with Scala 2.11.  If you must not use Spark 3.0 functionality, then I recommend to use SCC 2.5.0 with Spark 2.x

Comment: Pls recommend which scala version with Spark 3.0 ?

Comment: Spark 3.0 is compiled only with Scala 2.12.  I'm not sure if your Zeppelin itself supports Spark 3.0 - have you compiled it yourself?

Comment: I use Spark 3.0 with latest Zeppelin. I install scala 2.12 but I still have this error org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Lscala/Function1;Lscala/runtime/IntRef;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: What is the version of Zeppelin

Comment: Even I have same problem.. with zeplin 0.9 anyone got solution

Comment: The error about TraversableOne appears to be an incompatibility between minor versions of scala library. In my case, Zeppelin and Spark has 2.12.12, while Cassandra connector had 2.12.11. Excluding org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.11 from casandra connector appears to fix the issue (so far)